# how to find the sum of all of the numbers that correspond to certain words in a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, return, function

So if I have a dictionary like this:

```
a = ['a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3]
```

Obviously the sum of these three numbers would be six. How do I find the sum in any such list. I mean something like:

```
def compute_sum(a):
    total = 0
    for n in a:
        total += prices[n]
    return total
```

So am I right that that means I can return the sum of any list like that? Are there any other methods? How would you do it using the same or a different function?

Comment: What error do you get? We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: seems to be correct. did you try it?

Comment: `food` is the function argument and also the iterator in the `for loop`.

Comment: ok. change food to something else. you would also need the shopping_list to be passed as an argument

Comment: why is there even an argument passed into that function?

Comment: should this `def compute_bill(food):` be `def compute_bill(shopping_list):`?

Comment: @user2963623:

I totally agree with you. That's sort of what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If `total` and `prices[food]` are of the same type, there is not anything wrong with the statement. However, if you try to add (or concatenate) different types, you will most definitely encounter an error.

Secondly, you should pass `shopping_list` as argument in a function to be iterated, not `food`. So, the parameter name that function receives should be changed.

And thirdly, the `total` variable should be **inside** the function, not outside. In the the way you have written this, you will get `UnboundLocalError : local variable 'total' referenced before assignment` upon execution. Functions have their own local scope in which variables are defined separately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your loop slightly.
assuming shopping_list is something like `shopping_list = {'bread':1.00, 'eggs':0.99}` then you can do this:

```
def compute_bill(shopping_list):
    total = 0.0
    for food in shopping_list.keys():
        total += shopping_list[food]
    return total
```

Comment: It says there's a separate prices list

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by there's a separate prices list? Is it `food = ['bread', 'eggs']` and `prices = [1.00, 0.99]` or something like that and not actually a dictionary?

Comment: Never mind... I thought the 'shopping_list' is a list and the 'prices' is a dictionary. The question is ambiguous!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what the food variable is supposed to mean! Based on my comprehension of the question here's the code:

```
def compute_bill(shopping_list, prices):
    total = 0
    for food in shopping_list:
        total += prices[food]
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(food_prices[food] for food in shopping_list)
```

should work fine if you ask me

however here is your method fixed so it works ...

```
def compute_bill(): #no argument needed
    total = 0 #initialize total to zero in your method
    for food in shopping_list:
        total += prices[food]
    return total
```

Comment: Wouldn't this raise `NameError: shopping_list is not defined`?

Comment: why do you think that? he has shopping list defined somewhere ... (as evidenced in OP's original question in which he references without showing it ...)  (however as an aside I do think you are right that is the intended behaviour ... (ie shopping list is passed into the fn) ,+1 to your answer)

Comment: its not in another module its just defined somewhere ... in the same file ... not included in the code the OP provided (IE its in this file scope)  ... again in the OP's question you can see him reference it in the method and the error he got was not a nameError, which leads me to believe that it is somewhere that includes the method scope ...  (I did +1 your answer because I do think that is more likely his intended behaviour but it is not the problem he is encountering here)

Comment: No, Joran Beasley is right, I am wrong, the function _first_ look in local scope for variable, if not found, the function then looks in a global scope. But another error might be lurking here - `food` will sequentaly gets the **values** from shopping_list, not indexes, so the next statement `prices[food]` might surprise with `IndexError: list index out of range`...

Comment: no you are incorrect ... `for item in some_dict` will iterate over the keys ... not the values and `food_prices` is a dictionary not a list according to OP question ... if `shopping_list` is actually a list it will still iterate over the item names in the list ... which it the "looks up" in his database of prices (really he is just using a dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def compute_bill(food):
    for food,prices in shopping_list:
        total += prices
    return total
```

Some how cann't indent it

Answer (score 0):

how I'd do it:

```
shopping_list = []
prices = {"food_item": price_in_decimal, ... }

for item in stuff_you_want_to_buy:
    shopping_list.append(item)

def compute_bill(shopping_list):
    total = 0
    for item in shopping_list:
        try:
            total += prices[item]
        except KeyError as e:
            # that item does not have a price, handle it
    return total
```

Even better (but more complex):

```
class FoodItem(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        """Creates a new food object given its name and price as strings"""
        import decimal
        self.name = name
        self.price = decimal.Decimal(price)
    def __hash__(self):
        return (self.name, self.price)
        # This lets us use it as a dictionary key later

list_of_foods = [FoodItem("Apple","0.50"), FoodItem("Ham","6.50"), FoodItem("Milk","3.00"), ... ]

shopping_cart = list()
shopping_cart.append(list_of_foods[0])
shopping_cart.append(list_of_foods[0])
shopping_cart.append(list_of_foods[2])
# Two apples and a gallon of milk

def compute_bill(shopping_cart):
    return sum([item.price for item in shopping_cart])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the correct code:

```
def compute_bill(food):
total = 0
for n in food:
    total += prices[n]
return total
```

It turns out I should have made the list food, as opposed to making a different list with food as a parameter. Thanks.